# Deletion in Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Why is deletion in a BST a O(log(n)) operation. As i undersand it involves freeing a node and pointing the parent's reference to `NULL`. Shouldn't this take O(1)

Comment: It is O(log n) only in balanced trees...

Comment: @Moron: which makes it O(lg *n*) **expected time** in a non-self balancing BST.

Comment: @lars: Agree. Guess who upvoted your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how to delete a node which has two children -- the tree must be restructured so that the children find suitable new parents. Detailed explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion). Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(lg *n*) expected if you start from the root of the tree: then you have to search for the element to be deleted, and then for its in-order successor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a node and **all its children** then it is simple, but you have to rebuild the children if you wanto to keep sort order.

Comment: Well even in that case, it would only be O(1) if you already had the (internal) Node you wanted to delete. Usually the delete has to start at the root and search for the correct node from the given value which is O(log n) in itself.

Comment: No, this takes O(k) where *k* is the number of children of the node, assuming manual memory management (otherwise you'll pay for the garbage collection later). Besides, it's not a sensible operation unless you're deleting a range and establishing that the range is entirely below the node takes O(lg *n*) time.

Answer (score 0):

Deletion in a binary search tree is O(h) where h is the height of the tree.

Now that u haven't mentioned whether the tree is balanced or not the worst case complexity for an unbalanced tree would be O(n), i.e. when it is a degenerate tree.

In case the b.s.t is one of the balanced ones(Avl, red black etc.), then worst case complexity would be O(lg n) as the height of virtually all balanced b.s.t. is K*(lg n).

For example, for avl tree k = 1 and for red black tree K = 2.